# how/where to define/pass parameters in cloudformation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am learning aws SAM Cli. I created a project for a lambda function. I want to be able to pass a parameter to this cloudformation template that my python code can read and use when the lambda function executes. how/where do I indicate this in my cloudformation template file below. such that, either i can specify a default value for that parameter or override it when i create the stack from my template.

template.yaml -

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Lambda SAM Template
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 60

Resources:
  mysamplefunction:
    Properties:
      CodeUri: s3://some-bucket/qhfqep238974384y
      Description: some app
      FunctionName: mysamplefunction
      Handler: main.lambda_handler
      Role: arn:aws:iam::0949928960903:role/LambdaRole
      Runtime: python3.7
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
...
```

main.py

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print('parameter passed to cloud formation template');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add a top level parameters section to your template, with a structure like the below example.

```
Parameters: 
  InstanceTypeParameter: 
    Type: String
    Default: t2.micro
    AllowedValues: 
      - t2.micro
      - m1.small
      - m1.large
    Description: Enter t2.micro, m1.small, or m1.large. Default is t2.micro.
```

You can then reference these in your template using the [Ref intrinsic function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html) such as the example below.

```
Ec2Instance:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
  Properties:
    InstanceType:
      Ref: InstanceTypeParameter
    ImageId: ami-0ff8a91507f77f
```

For getting this into your Lambda code you would probably want to use an environment variable within your [Lambda CloudFormation resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-function.html#sam-function-environment).

More information about parameters can be found on the [parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) page. By using the Ref intrinsic function with a suitable [environment variable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html) name you could then reference this within your code such as in the example below.

```
import os
region = os.environ['MY_VARIABLE']
```

Comment: thanks. that's exactly , what i wanted to know. how do i actually map between 'MY_VARIABLE' in my python code vs what i define in the cloudformation template?

Comment: When you define the environment variable (see this example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-environment.html) you would use the ref function for the value part of the key value combination. This is similar to https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/blob/master/community/services/Lambda/LambdaSample.yaml#L78 but using ref instead (although sub works too).